# OnBackButtonPressed with keyboard opened

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I need to update the UI of my android application when the keyboard is closed (using the back button). When I override `OnBackButtonPressed`, it fires like it should but not when the keyboard is up. Is there an other method used for that, or a listener of sorts I could use?

Comment: @ADM I never said I wanted to prevent the keyboard from closing, I just want a callback when it _does_ closes, in order to change a state on one of my controls

Comment: What you need is keyboard close callback.It was not clear from your question . Now it is.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the edittext and use below code:

```
public class EditTextBackEvent extends Edittext
{
    private EditTextImeBackListener mOnImeBack;

    public EditTextBackEvent(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public EditTextBackEvent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public EditTextBackEvent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (mOnImeBack != null) mOnImeBack.onImeBack(this, this.getText().toString());
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    public void setOnEditTextImeBackListener(EditTextImeBackListener listener) {
        mOnImeBack = listener;
    }

    public interface EditTextImeBackListener {
        void onImeBack(EditTextBackEvent ctrl, String text);
    }
}
```

then you can use EdittetBackEvent.setOnEditTextImeBackListener()

Comment: I think question is about `xamarin` C#.

Comment: oh sorry you must be right. i didnt realize the xamarin tag :) may be this answer can help someone else. so i didnt remove it.

Comment: You can explain the concept of answer . May be it will help OP in implement the same in `xamarin` .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the keyboard for example in a form after the user inputs the information, what you can do is hide the keyboard and add the behaviour that you want after the user types into the last editText:

```
EditText lastEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.whatever);

lastEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                hideKeyboard(v);
                doWhateverYouWant();
            }
        }
    });
```

The method to hide the keyboard:

```
 private void hideKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```